# Mongoose / MongoDB aggregation query deep populate

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Looking to find a way to perform an aggregation and then perform another join for all results in the result set in Mongoose.

I have three tables:

Groups -> GroupId

GroupLikes -> GroupId | AnimalId (ref to Animal)

Animals -> AnimalId | etc

I would like to have one query which retrieves all groups and finds all the animals a specific group liked.

I have the following code so far to retrieve all group likes:

```
 GroupModel.aggregate([
        {
            "$lookup": {
                "from": 'GroupLikes',
                "localField": "_id",
                "foreignField": "GroupId",
                "as": "group_likes"
            },
        },
    ])
```

I'm unsure of how to populate the animal document for each document in group_likes. How can I achieve this?